# How to keep html tags when writing a ElementTree tree to disk?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, character-encoding, elementtree

I'm trying to write an XML tree to disk using Python's xml.etree.ElementTree to reproduce an example document given to me. The target XML document has fields in it that look like:

```
<title>
This is a test of <br/> Hershey's <sup>&$174;</sup> chocolate factory machine <br/>
</title>
```

My problem is that whenever I try to write the text to disk using ElementTree's `.write()` method I can't achieve the above output. Either the html tags will get converted to `&lt;br&gt;` or the trademark symbol (the &#174 stuff) will show up as the actual symbol.  Is there a way to encode my text to get the above output (where the trademark is represented by the &#174 characters but the html is html?). I've tried different encoding options in the write method but nothing seems to do the trick.

**Edit**: Here is a minimal working example. Take an input XML template file like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<document>
        <title> Text to replace </title>
</document>
```

and we try to modify the text like so

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('example.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
to_sub_text = "This is a test of <br/> Hershey's <sup>&$174;</sup> chocolate factory machine"
spot = root.find('title')
spot.text = to_sub_text
tree.write('example_mod.xml', encoding='UTF-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

this will write to file a file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<document>
        <title>This is a test of &lt;br/&gt; Hershey's &lt;sup&gt;&amp;$174;&lt;/sup&gt; chocolate factory machine</title>
</document>
```

As I said, the document I'm trying to replicate leaves those html tags as tags. My questions are:

1. Can I modify my code to do that?
2. Is doing this good practice, or would have it been better to leave it as it currently is (and thus I need to talk to the team requesting I provide it to them in this way)?

Comment: 1) Please show us your code. 2) The "&#174 stuff" should look like this: `&#174;` (with `#` and `;`).

Comment: Thanks. I should have included a full example when I first posted. See above.

Comment: `&$174;` should be `&#174;`.

Comment: *"Either the html tags will get converted to &lt;br&gt;"* - That's what happens when you save text to an XML document. It will get XML-escaped. That the text accidentally also is HTML source code does not matter at all. Text is text. If you want to save a sub-tree of actual nodes to the XML element, you need to create them. You can't do `spot.text = 'a string with a couple of angle brackets'` expect that to get different treatment than `spot.text = 'literally any other string'`.

Comment: *"or the trademark symbol (will show up as the actual symbol."* - Yeah. So what? Job of the XML file is to transport the *character* (the trademark symbol), not to retain your favorite representation of it. `&#xae;`, `&#174;` and `®` all represent the same thing. From the XML document's perspective at the time of writing the file - why use 6 characters (`&#174;`) when you can do it with one (`®`)?

Comment: Thanks for the additional comments, @Tomalak. As I said elsewhere, I don't have any particular favorite representation of how stuff is written to disk. I'm trying to reproduce a document that was passed to me from a client (but whom I do not have a direct line of contact at the moment), and trying to understand to what extent it is possible to reproduce it and what aspects are fundamentally not possible without doing something non-standard or hacky. If I do not reproduce their document exactly, I want to be able to speak with more authority about why that's the case.

Comment: Fair enough. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `spot.text = to_sub_text` assignment does not work. An element's `text` property contains plain text only. It is not possible to use it to add both text and subelements.

What you can do is to create a new `<title>` element object and append that to the root:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
 
tree = ET.parse('example.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
 
# Remove the old title element
old_title = root.find('title')
root.remove(old_title)
 
# Add a new title
new_title = "<title>This is a test of <br/> Hershey's <sup>&#174;</sup> chocolate factory machine</title>"
root.append(ET.fromstring(new_title))
 
# Prettify output (requires Python 3.9) 
ET.indent(tree)
 
# Use encoding='US-ASCII' to force output of character references for non-ASCII characters
tree.write('example_mod.xml', encoding='US-ASCII', xml_declaration=True)
```

Output in example_mod.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='US-ASCII'?>
<document>
  <title>This is a test of <br /> Hershey's <sup>&#174;</sup> chocolate factory machine</title>
</document>
```

Comment: Thank you. Knowing that I can't use the text attribute like that is really helpful, and this is the closest process to get to the document I've been asked to reproduce. The only difference is that the encoding header in the document I've been asked to reproduce says that the encoding is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`. But if I specify that as the encoding in the write step I do not get the same output (registered trademark gets represented by a symbol). Is it your understanding that that's fundamentally just the way it has to be for that encoding type?

Comment: I do not have a line of communication to the development team of our client at the moment, so I cannot communicate to them about how they are reading these documents or how they are produced (some aspects might even be created by hand!). But I'm trying to understand what aspects of the document reproduction can be done and what aspects are based around my own ignorance of different encoding schemes and such.

Comment: *Is it your understanding that that's fundamentally just the way it has to be for that encoding type?* Yes, it is. The ® character and `&#174;` are different representations of the exact same thing. With UTF-8, the actual character is used.

Comment: Btw, us-ascii is in fact the default encoding in the `write()` method. It does not have to be specified explicitly (https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write).

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the info. The file I was asked to reproduce must have been created in a funny way then, since the UTF-8 heading is consistent with the representation of that character. Appreciate all your help on this!